# Find hidden folders/files/partition

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace-2, hidden

I connect my samsung galaxy ace 2 into my Windows pc, and there are 2 directories shown. My SD card, and the internal storage, named `Phone`. Both of these seem to be empty. the SD card directory, named `Card` Says that there is `3.57 GB Free of 3.68 GB`, yet opening it shows **Nothing.** `Phone` says there is 1GB of 1GB free, and there's nothing inside. I have come to realise that what i have emptied out is just data the apps collect and use, not the apps themselves. All aps remain on my phone and work fine. **Yet it says it is completely empty.**

Now, what my phone says is a completely different story. It thinks the total space is `1.2 GB` and there is `1.1 GB` free, with `71.16 MB` being used for applications and the rest for Misc files. There are only slight differences in the SD card, with `3.69 GB` Total and `3.58 GB` Free.

So, My Phone and PC contradict each other in pretty much all aspects. I have windows setup to show hidden files. But it isn't. I want to see **all** the files on my phone, from my computer. How can I acheive this? Searching for this issue on google doesn't help much from what I have found.

EDIT: The samsung website specifies the phone as having "Built in memory 4GB (2GB user memory)". So why is it I only get half of what i'm supposed to have?

Answer (score 0):

if your phone shows up as a local drive (like a pendrive)

go to start type cmd then Ctrl+Shift+Enter(to open with admin privileges) then type

attrib -s -h /d /s [X]:\*.*

where [X] is the drive letter of the memory of the phone you want to see (dont type the "[]")

Comment: It shows up as "Phone", with an icon mildly representing one.